# set jquery variable from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, variables

I'm trying to create jQuery slider which will be configurable , but i encoutred for me unsolved issue and that's how to store settings. Let's say, there is variable telling my slider time after which slider must show next slide. Call him

```
var time = 1000;
```

The question is, how to set it from php? I don't like using inline javascripts, i want to have separate slider so no writing it to template is solution. Also I don't want to load it with ajax, it take some time.

I thought about two solutions:

1 generate whole file everytime settings change, for example

> var time = {time};

and rewrite it with php

2 use some hidden form elements, or some elements

> `<input type="hidden" class="slider-time" value="1000" />`

and load it from them on document ready

```
var time = $('.slider-time').val();
```

Maybe all my ideas are stupid and there is, better, more effective way how to do that, so if you know, can you tell me? I would be glad for any ideas, thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between a hidden input field (generated with inline php) or javascript (generated with inline php)? Why don't you want to use inline php?

Comment: @Eich - I misread that just like you did.  I believe he means inline JS; not inline PHP.

Comment: I believe it's too messy to put those two things in one file...at least for me it's better to create few css and js files than put it all in html or tpl file....and second idea, i believe that i read somewhere that js and css files are cached by browser while script directly in tpl will be reloaded after every page

Comment: i edited question, so it show javascript instead of script

Comment: Why don't you set a global JS variable (without php)? Or is the value saved in your database? In my opinion this is a JS setting, so it's OK to set them once inside your JS-Code (without php :).

Comment: It is JS setting but i want it to be customized by user without javascript knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to echo your value right inside your Javascript:

```
var time = <?php echo $time_value ?>;
```

Comment: that's possible only when it's directly in template file, or is it posible to run php in js files?

Comment: If you want PHP to do the work for you, you'll need to place your JS in a file that PHP parses.  That potentially means inline.

Answer (score 0):

include a PHP file which returns you the data and then echo it like what we see in wordpress theme options plugins.